# Does Myspace automatically crawl and open fake accounts, from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, myspace

I have seen a Myspace account which uses the profile image on Facebook. The age and relationship status is right, but they were hidden from public view. The profile image on Facebook is a few days old; however it is six hours old on Myspace. The profile image on Myspace is in very bad quality.

Comment: Do you have links and/or screenshots?

Comment: @phwd, I have found it. There is sync application called "Mashup with Facebook"

Answer (score 1):

There is an MySpace application in Facebook which enables to integrate MySpace withFacebook http://voices.yahoo.com/myspace-facebook-integrate-through-click-of-7234168.html